# C++ adjacent values

Tags: c++, algorithm, vector

I saw the following question, while managed to solve it in O(n^2) I think we can do better.

> Given a vector of integers return the maximum number of non-adjacent
> copies of similar number.

For example, given: [9,2,3,4,0,4,5,6,0,8]

we can see that we have 2 non adjacent 0 and 2 non adjacent 4 (the rest are ones) so the answer is max(2,2)=2;

given: [4,4,4,4,4]

we have 3 non adjacent 4 so the answer is 3.
we take first 4, then we can't take the one next to it (they are adjacent) so we take the one after and so on.

My solution:
Iterate over the vector and check how many non adjacent copies we see from the current number, if it's bigger than current max we update max accordingly.

**Q: How can we solve this more efficiently?**

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear by "I think we can do better." can this be solved more efficiently?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please learn how to [edit] your questions to improve them.

Comment: In your 2nd example, I don't understand how you get 3 copies only.

Comment: `map<int,int> counts; for i in 0 to size: if v[i] is different than v[i - 1] then counts[v[i]]++; return max entry in counts`

Comment: @Jeffrey sorry not clear to me, will update the question. I'm looking for algorithm too

Comment: @DrewDormann for 2nd example how this will work

Comment: So any length of n adjacent values contributes n/2 if even and (n+1)/2 if odd. iterate once through the list and keep  track of each running total of contribution. linear time?

Comment: @daniel what I gave you is the algorithm (with a little bit not elaborated). Now, try to implement it.

Comment: @Jeffrey maybe i'm misreading but doesn't that result in  a result of 1 instead of 3 for `[4,4,4,4,4]`?

Comment: yeah, I meant, for all value, if it's different than previous **or if you skipped previous because it was not different** increment counter

Comment: @Ruzihm not linear time, you need to check how many non adjacent copes 9 have and 2 have and 3 have and 4 have (in first example) and return the maximum so it's O(n^2)

Comment: @daniel That doesn't explain why not. You start at v[0]=9, say current_val = 9, current_count = 1, go v[1]=2, set totals[9] += (current_count+1)/2 then current_val=2, current_count=1, and keep going to v[2]. you don't have to start over at v[0] again... Jeffrey's aglo is mostly the same as mine only with remembering if you skipped the previous item instead of counting contiguous sequence size. same complexity, but I like his better

Comment: @daniel Did you find an answer to this question?

Answer (score 2):

If you're fine with using O(n) space, you can use buckets for the values you see to achieve an O(n) runtime.

The easiest way to implement that would be with a map. ie:

```
std::pair<int, int> max_adj(std::vector<int> arr) {
    std::map<int, int> buckets;
    
    for(int x = 0; x < arr.size(); x++) {
        // Loop to eat up adjacent values
        int in_a_row = 1;
        for(int curr = x++;
            x < arr.size() && arr[curr] == arr[x];
            x++, in_a_row++) { }
        x--; // The loop will increment x one past last dupe, so go back
        
        // Only count every other adjacent value seen
        buckets[arr[x]] += (in_a_row + 1) / 2;
    }
    
    // Find the most seen
    std::map<int, int>::iterator mx = std::max_element
    (
        buckets.begin(), buckets.end(),
        [] (const std::pair<int, int> &p1, const std::pair<int, int> &p2) {
            return p1.second < p2.second;
        }
    );
    
    if(mx != buckets.end()) {
        return *mx;
    }
    return std::pair<int, int>(-1, -1);
}
```

Live example: https://ideone.com/v9OOIA

Comment: `std::max_element` might return something you can't dereference if `arr.size() is 0`

Comment: With `[1 2 1 1]`, you will get an answer of 1, if I understand well your algorithm. I was expecting an answer of 2, but I am not sure either to understand the problem!

Comment: @Jeff good call. I've edited to cover that. Thanks!

Comment: @Damien from my understanding of the problem, that's correct. `1` should be counted twice: once for index 0, and once for index 2 (but not for index 3!)

Answer (score 0):

This problem can be solved by creating an array which contains number and it's index as showed below,

original array = `[9, 2, 3, 4, 0, 4, 5, 6, 0, 8]`,
number index array = [`9`, 0], [`2`, 1], [`3`, 2], [`4`, 3], [`0`, 4], [`4`, 5], [`5`, 6], [`6`, 7], [`0`, 8], [`8`, 9]
Here first element of `std::pair` is number itself and second element is index of number.
After it, sort this array by numbers and result would be as follows,
[`0`, 8], [`0`, 4], [`2`, 1], [`3`, 2], [`4`, 5], [`4`, 3], [`5`, 6], [`6`, 7], [`8`, 9], [`9`, 0]
Purpose of sorting is to bring same numbers adjacent to each other. Once same numbers are adjacent a simple iteration is required to find answer. Let's see how it works,

First number in sorted array is `0` and by finding `upper bound` of `0` will give all adjacent `0`, it means following will be available,
[`0`, 8], [`0`, 4]
But As you can see above these entries are not in order of index entry of index `4` is following entry of index `8` and this is because `std::sort` is not a stable sort, it means relative order of elements are not preserved. So before proceeding these elements have to sort again by index and result would be

[`0`, 4], [`0`, 8]
As showed above index `4` and `8` are not adjacent `4 + 1 != 8`, and count of non adjacent numbers is `two`.
All entries of `0` are examined, and algorithm will consider next number which is `2`, but as you see above in array there is only one entry of number `2` which is `[2, 1]` and due to this next number will be considered, same will happen for all numbers so let directly see number `4` and it has more then one entries as showed below,
[`4`, 5], [`4`, 3]
then sort these entries by index,

[`4`, 3], [`4`, 5]
here again indexes are not adjacent indexes `3 + 1 != 5`, and count of non adjacent number is `two`. Same process will be applied on all numbers and final answer will be max non adjacent number `count = 2`
For other example of array `[4, 4, 4, 4, 4]` final number and index array of it will be,
[`4`, 0], [`4`, 1], [`4`, 2], [`4`, 3], [`4`, 4]
And as you can see index `0`, `2`, `4` are not adjacent indexes and max non adjacent number `count = 3`

```
#include <iostream>

#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using std::cout;

std::size_t countNonAdjacentEntries(std::vector<std::pair<int, std::size_t>>::const_iterator firstIt,
                                    std::vector<std::pair<int, std::size_t>>::const_iterator lastIt){


    std::size_t count = 0;

    for(std::vector<std::pair<int, std::size_t>>::const_iterator preIt = firstIt, it = preIt + 1; lastIt != it;){

        if(preIt->second + 1 != it->second){

            ++count;

            preIt = it;
            ++it;
        }
        else{
            ++it;
        }
    }

    ++count;
    return count;
}

std::size_t maxNonAdjacentNumber(const std::vector<int>& numbers){

    std::vector<std::pair<int, std::size_t>> numAndIndex;
    numAndIndex.reserve(numbers.size());

    for(std::vector<int>::size_type i = 0, numbersCount = numbers.size(); i < numbersCount; ++i){

        numAndIndex.emplace_back(numbers[i], i);
    }

    std::sort(numAndIndex.begin(), numAndIndex.end(),
              [](const std::pair<int, std::size_t>& a, const std::pair<int, std::size_t>& b){
        return a.first < b.first;});

    std::size_t count = 0;

    for(std::vector<std::pair<int, std::size_t>>::const_iterator it = numAndIndex.cbegin(), endIt = numAndIndex.cend();
        endIt != it; ){

        std::vector<std::pair<int, std::size_t>>::const_iterator upBoundIt = std::upper_bound( it + 1, endIt, it->first,
                    [](int val, const std::pair<int, std::size_t>& ele){return val < ele.first;});

        if(upBoundIt - it > 1){

            std::sort(numAndIndex.begin(), numAndIndex.end(),
                      [](const std::pair<int, std::size_t>& a, const std::pair<int, std::size_t>& b){
                return a.second < b.second;});

            count = std::max(count, countNonAdjacentEntries(it, upBoundIt));
            it = upBoundIt;
        }
        else{
            ++it;
        }
    }

    return count;
}

int main(){

    cout<< "[9, 2, 3, 4, 0, 4, 5, 6, 0, 8] => "<< maxNonAdjacentNumber({9, 2, 3, 4, 0, 4, 5, 6, 0, 8})<< '\n';
    cout<< "[4, 4, 4, 4, 4] => "<< maxNonAdjacentNumber({4, 4, 4, 4, 4})<< '\n';
}
```

*Output*

```
[9, 2, 3, 4, 0, 4, 5, 6, 0, 8] => 2
[4, 4, 4, 4, 4] => 3
```

Answer (score -1):

unique to remove duplicates, sort to clump remaining, then find longest run.

```
template<class T, class A>
std::optional<T> most_runs_of( std::vector<T, A> r ) {
  if (r.empty()) return std::nullopt;
  r.erase( std::unique( begin(r), end(r) ), end(r) );
  std::sort( begin(r), end(r) );
  T winner = r.front();
  std::size_t winner_count = 0;
  T const* cur = nullptr;
  std::size_t cur_count = 0;
  for (T const& e:r) {
    if (e == winner)
    {
      ++winner_count;
      continue;
    }
    if (cur && *cur==e) {
      ++cur_count;
      if (cur_count > winner_count) {
        winner = e;
        winner_count = cur_count;
        cur = nullptr;
        continue;
      }
    }
    cur = std::addressof(e);
    cur_count = 1;
  }
  return winner;
}
```

This copies the `std::vector` and does it in-place in the copy in O(nlgn) and O(n) space.

If you don't need the `std::vector` after you call the above, `std::move` it into the algorithm.

Comment: What about the adjacent part?

Comment: `Eliminates all except the first element from every consecutive group` so the OP's 2nd example [4,4,4,4,4] would be reduced to [4]?